# Finding centralizer in a group.

Tags: group-theory

Find the centralizer of $(13)(24)$ in $S_4$.

The only way I can think of doing this is by brute-force, wherein find
$$g\in S_4 \  : \ (13)(24)g=g(13)(24).$$
But $S_4$ has $4!$ elements, which would hint that doing it via brute force is not the correct way. Any ideas?

Also, is there a quick way to find the conjugates of the element in $S_4$ also? Aside from a similar brute force method.

Comment: What you have written would be the centralizer, not the conjugates.

Comment: Yep. My mistake. I'll fix that.

Comment: Conjugates have the same cycle structure. So $(13)(24)$ has $(12)(34)$ and $(14)(23)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Convention: $\sigma\circ \tau$ means first apply $\tau$, then $\sigma$. So $\sigma\circ\tau(x)=\sigma(\tau(x)).$

(2) Show: if $\sigma$ takes $i$ to $j$ then $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ takes $\tau(i)$ to $\tau(j)$, i.e. 
$$\sigma(i)=j \Longrightarrow \tau\sigma\tau^{-1} (\tau(i))=\tau(j).$$

(3) Let $\sigma=(13)(24)$ and suppose $\tau$ commutes with $\sigma$, so $\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma$, i.e. $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=\sigma$.

(4) Since $\sigma$ takes $1$ to $3$, hence $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ takes $\tau(1)$ to $\tau(3)$.

(5) But $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=\sigma$, so (4) says 
 $$\sigma \mbox{ takes }\tau(1)  \mbox{ to } \tau(3).$$

Also since $\sigma$ takes $3$ to $1$, conclude that

$$\sigma \mbox{ takes }\tau(3)  \mbox{ to } \tau(1).$$

(6) Thus, $\tau(1)$ and $\tau(3)$ are numbers in $\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $\sigma$ interchanges them. But $\sigma$ interchanges $\{1, 3\}$ and it also interchanges $\{2,4\}$. This gives following possibilities of $\tau$:
$$\{ \tau(1),\tau(3)\}=\{1,3\}  \mbox{ or } \{ \tau(1),\tau(3)\}=\{2,4\}.$$

(7) Similarly, $\sigma$ takes $3$ to $4$ and $4$ to $3$, conclude that 
$$\{ \tau(2),\tau(4)\}=\{1,3\}  \mbox{ or } \{ \tau(2),\tau(4)\}=\{2,4\}.$$

(8) From (6) and (7), we obtain 4 possibilities of $\tau$; what are they?

Comment: Note: while deducing from (6) (7), the possibilities of $\tau$, we will obtain 16 such; but since $\tau$ is **permutation (bijection)**, we actually get $4$ only; what are they?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the formula for the conjugates of a cycle: for any $\sigma\in S_n$:
$$\sigma(i_1\,i_2\,\dotsm\, i_r)\sigma^{-1}=\bigl(\sigma(i_1)\sigma(i_2)\dots\sigma(i_r)\bigr) $$

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see how that would simplify the problem that much. Wouldn't you still need to calculate this for each element in $S_4$?

Comment: Actually I answered the initial formulation of your question (conjugates). For the new formulation, it automates some calculations. Furthermore, you know the centraliser is a subgroup of $S_4$, and its index in $S_4$ is known.

Comment: It is not true that you need to calculate it for each $\sigma \in S_n$, because the $\sigma(i_k)$ for $k>1$ are determined uniquely by $\sigma(i_1)$ in a centralizer computation. So, for example, if you were computing the centralizer of a $5$-cycle $(1,2,3,4,5)$ in $S_5$, then you would only need to consider the $5$ possibilites for $\sigma(1)$ rather than all $120$ permutations. Shortcuts like this are used in computer programs to compute centralizers.